# Purchasing a flight sim, am I being overly paranoid?

Tags: halal-haram

Assalamu Alaikom,

I enjoy playing flight simulators. I have come to find out that the developer of one of the military flight sims I have been looking to purchase also has military contracts on the side. Meaning they develop specialized, private sims for use by a couple of air forces for training purposes (all non-Muslim, and who have actively been involved in campaigns on Muslim lands).

Does this make it Haram to purchase from said developer? Would there be (indirectly) blood on my hands? Where do we draw the line?

These videos could be relevant to put things into perspective:

- https://youtu.be/feiPqkvSfPM
- https://youtu.be/gQxrHFDRV-0

Comment: 'Paranoid' is a bad way of phrasing this. I would even say it is *haram* in this context. 'Sensitive' is clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Waalaikumsalam,

1. The original law of dealing business with Non-Muslims including Jews and all their companies (ex : developers) is **Halal** as long as the transaction was made in accordance with Islamic terms of sale.
2. The existence of these companies in the Jewish state and their business cannot be regarded as aiding the work of anti-muslim terrorism. Therefore, any such evidence is not strong enough to convince 'direct' aid to anti-muslim work or other evil acts.
3. The original law will only be changed to **Haraam** transacting or compelling them to boycott if the supreme Islamic government, the *Khalifah* (leader) of the entire Muslim world, is leading a boycott to achieve certain goals for Islam.

Wallahualam.

Answer (score 0):

Britain has conducted dishonourable colonial wars in the past, does this make being a British citizen haram? By your argument that seems a possibility, likewise, say with being a citizen of the United States, or indeed Pakistan, which conducted a war of aggression against Bangladesh (this actually was a civil war since Bangladesh was East Pakistan then).

Given that there is no overall ecclesiastical hierarchy in Islam, as say there is in Catholicism, the line to draw is in your own conscious and your understanding of Islam; the latter typically defers to the consensus of the *ummah*, the people of Islamic faith; and just a few people that you might find here and there - for example at Islam.SE